Can I modify either inf or sys files to install a driver for a different device?
I understand driver signing will have to be disabled. I have an Avermedia Live Game 4k capture card which based on research and linux based github repos is similar enough to a CL511HN.
I want to use their sdk which supports CL511HN but not the live gamer. So I have two options, either modify the sdk, which seems feasible based on strings I found using Ghidra or force the driver to recognize the Live gamer as a CL511HN.
I'm not particularly familiar with windows drivers. I have a cat file, a sys file and an inf file.
If its as simple as disabling signing and modifying a few lines I'll take that route. Otherwise I'll try to modify the sdk to recognize the Live Gamer.
What lines in an inf file describe the intended device? Such as:
[Manufacturer]
%ProviderName%=AVXGC573,NTAMD64 

[AVXGC573.NTAMD64]
%AVXGC573Cap.DeviceDesc%=AVXGC573Cap,PCI\VEN_1461&DEV_0054&SUBSYS_57301461


"What lines in an inf file describe the intended device?" - The line under [AVXGC573.NTAMD64] but all that will do is allow Windows to attempt to use the driver with the device it DOES NOT guarantee the driver will be functional.
